# set a radio button value based on option select using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set a radio button based on selecting an option in a select box.

For example, There are 5 select options available, If I select the first option, first radio button should be checked. Likewise for the rest of the things. I am working only with Javascript.

I have tried the below code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <form name="myform" action="">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
                <br>    
                    <label for="select_value" onchange="myFunction()">Select Number</label>
                    <select name="select_value">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                <br>
                    <label for="radio_value">Select Position</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="First">First</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Second">Second</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Third">Third</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fourth">Fourth</input>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fifth">Fifth</input>
                <br>
                    <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementsByName("select_value").value;
                document.getElementsByName('radio_value')[x].checked=true;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o9jxf2zz/1/)

Comment: In this particular case, the value of the select elements aligns with the index of the related radio button plus 1, so you could do: `document.getElementsByName('radio_value')[++x].checked = true;` but that's not a general solution.

Comment: @RobG I have tried in my localhost about what you said, there is no selected radio button.

Comment: Ah yes, you also need `x = document.getElementsByName("select_value")[0].value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code to your javascript

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];

select.onchange = function(event) {
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="radio_value"]');

    btns[event.target.value].checked = true
}
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/tv6jrk0p/1)

***Documentation***

[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

[Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Comment: Please explain a bit. I am  a newbie in terms of Javascript. May I know what is the first line means.

Comment: with the first line you are getting the select element and after that we are setting an event handler that fires every time the value of select changes.

Comment: May i know why we user `[0]`?

Comment: because we want the first and only select element.

Comment: There is no need for `^=` in the selector, `=` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Following changes makes your example work :

1.

```
<select name="select_value" onchange="myFunction()">
```

2.

```
document.getElementsByName("select_value")[0].value;
```

3.

```
document.getElementsByName('radio_value')[x].checked=true;
```

4.

```
function should be in head section
```

### [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9jxf2zz/18/)

Comment: I can't able to select the first and last radio button using this fiddle

Comment: Then try : `document.getElementsByName('radio_value')[x].checked=true;` . Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o9jxf2zz/18/

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It is working for me. Use `parseInt` when getting the value of the `select box`. I have given an `id` to the `select box` and have used `x-1` while selecting the `radio buttons` as their index starts from `0`.

```
<form name="myform" action="">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name"></input>
        <br>    
            <label for="select_value" >Select Number</label>
            <select name="select_value" onchange="myFunction()">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
        <br>
            <label for="radio_value">Select Position</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="First">First</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Second">Second</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Third">Third</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fourth">Fourth</input>
            <input type="radio" name="radio_value" value="Fifth">Fifth</input>
        <br>
            <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {

        var x = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("select_value")[0].value);
        alert((x));
        document.getElementsByName('radio_value')[x-1].checked=true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I can't use id to select box

Comment: See the updated answer. It is using `getElementsByName` now. You need to use `[0]` as there can by many elements by the name `select` when the DOM is rendered. So that's why, using a `id` is preferred.

Comment: I knew it is necessary to use `id`. But my situation is I can't use id. Thanks for the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this out its working fine

<html>
                  <head>
                  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
                        type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <title>JS Test</title>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                  </head>
                  <body>
                        <div></div>
                        <div>
                            <form name="myform" action="">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name"></input>
                                <br>    
                                    <label for="select_value">Select Number</label>
                                    <select name="select_value" id = "select_value">
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                    </select>
                                <br>
                                    <label for="radio_value">Select Position</label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" id = "First" value="First">First</input>
                                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" id="Second" value="Second">Second</input>
                                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" id="Third" value="Third">Third</input>
                                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" id="Fourth" value="Fourth">Fourth</input>
                                    <input type="radio" name="radio_value" id="Fifth" value="Fifth">Fifth</input>
                                <br>
                                    <input type="submit" name="form_submit" value="Submit"></input>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                  </body>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $( "#select_value" ).change(function() {

                            var conceptName = $('#select_value').find(":selected").text();
                            if(conceptName=="1"){
                                $('#First').prop('checked',true);
                            }
                            else if(conceptName=="2"){

                                $('#Second').prop('checked',true);
                            }
                            else if(conceptName=="3"){

                                $('#Third').prop('checked',true);
                            }
                            else if(conceptName=="4"){

                                $('#Fourth').prop('checked',true);
                            }
                            else{

                                $('#Fifth').prop('checked',true);
                            }

                        });

                    </script>
                </html>
```

Comment: I can't use JQUERY friend. Thanks for your effort